# How can we get cve list under one cwe id?

Tags: owasp, cve

I want to fetch a list of **CVEs** using the **CWE ID** but could not find any references.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Update::

I have found the solution.
There is an API on  official NIST website(https://nvd.nist.gov/)
I am using it and its works perfectly as I wanted.